# Find the first three nonzero terms of the Maclaurin series for...

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

> Find the first three nonzero terms of the Maclaurin series for
>   $f(z)=\sin(z)e^{-3z}$

I tried:

$$\sin(z)=\sum^\infty_{i=0}\frac{(-1)^i}{(2i+1)!}z^{2i+1}$$ $$e^{-3z}=\sum^\infty_{j=0}\frac{(-3)^jz^j}{j!}$$

Thus,

$$\sin(z)e^{-3z}=\sum^\infty_{k=0}c_kz^k$$ for $k=2i+j+1$ and where $$c_k=\sum^k_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n(-3)^{k-n}}{(2n+1)!(k-n)!}$$Now for $i=0$, $j=0$, I got $k=1$, so $$c_1=-3-1/6=-19/6$$

Then, for $i=1$ and $j=1$, $k=4.$ So I would then need to find $c_4$. The third and final term would then be $c_7$ (when $i$  and $j = 2$).

Is this correct? Or do I just let $k=0,1,2,\dotsc$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truncate series to order three or more (any order at least three) and multiply them. The order three or less terms of the product of the two polynomials are the desired terms.

Comment: By order 3 do you mean find the terms where i,j = 0,1,2 for $sin(z)$ and $e^{-3z}$ individually?

Comment: I used order instead of degree, my bad. I meant the degree of the polynomial. For example, $e^{-3z} = 1 -3z + 4.5z^2-4.5z^3+O(z^4) = P_3(z) + O(z^4).$ Expand similarly the $\sin$ in such a way that $\sin(z) = Q_k(z) + O(z^{k+1})$ where $Q_k$ is a polynomial of degree three or more and the multiply $P$ and $Q,$ and from the multiplication take the all terms of degree at most three.

Comment: I got $1-3z+4.5z^2-14z^3/3$. Is this the final answer or do I take away the term $1$ or $14z^3/3$, thus leaving me with exactly 3 terms?

Comment: Actually, the question say “first three non-zero terms” Until the quadratic term is enough

Comment: So, just to make sure, I still have to truncate series to order 3?

Comment: Yes, because with order three you _ensure_ you won't miss anything needed. I don't know if I make sense of myself